# Formatting result from scan command in HBASE

Tags: hbase

I am trying to run **'scan'**   command on HABSE shell.

> scan 'table_name'

I am getting result as this:

```
ROW                             COLUMN+CELL                                                                             

000001bff3df$94a8a4c0$608812cf column=general:bcc, timestamp=1521624689099, value=                                     
 @bt2ta 
000001bff3df$94a8a4c0$608812cf column=general:cc, timestamp=1521624689099, value=                                      
 @bt2ta                                                                                                                 
 000001bff3df$94a8a4c0$608812cf column=general:from, timestamp=1521624689099, value="Ken Turner" <kmturner@flex.net>    
 @bt2ta
```

If you look at the result, it is not well formatted. I could not figure out what is ROW and what is COLUMN+CELL.

Que. Is there any way I can format this result for better readability?

Answer (score 2):

The `hbase shell` is not displaying the result properly due to terminal window limitation. Tr o output the scan result to a file.

- Go to shell command prompt (not in `hbase shell`)
- Execute the below command

  echo "scan 'table_name'" | hbase shell > myText

The output in `mytext` would not be wrapped on `key`. Once you have data in the file, you can use shell commands to format is further as per your requirement.

Comment: This becomes lengthy process. I was expecting something similar that we have in mysql, like using '\G' at end of query in mysql shows the result more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to depend on terminal settings.  I see column wrapping when I have TERM=dumb in my environment variables.  I don't see it when I have TERM=xterm or TERM=ansi

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, the solution did not work.